# Component does not change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, components, rendering

I am makeing my first steps in react. Now I want to fetch some data from thedogapi.com and and to show the results as cards below the search input.

But it is not working and I am not sure why:

```
let data = [];

function ApiSearch() {
    async function changeHandler(e) {

        //console.log('https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?q=' + e.target.value.toString());

        let response =
            await fetch('https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?q=' + e.target.value.toString(), {
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'x-api-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                },
            })
        data = await response.text();
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        ApiResults();
    }

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="fromAPISearch">
                <Form.Label>Search for a Breed</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Some breed.."
                    onChange={changeHandler}
                />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Save
            </Button>
            <Button variant="danger" type="reset">
                Reset
            </Button>
            <Button variant="warning" type="reset">
                Delete All Entries
            </Button>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

ApiResults() can show me the data due console.log() but it is not rendering anything here.

```
function ApiResults() {
    const results = [];

    data.forEach(d => {
        results.push(
            <Card key={d.id}>
                <Card.Body>
                    {d.name}
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        )
    })

    return (
        <Col>
            {
                results.map(
                    result => {return result}
                )
            }
        </Col>
    )
}
```

I Call 2 Components,  should be the one that shows the results that  gathers.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <br/>
                    <ApiSearch/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <ApiResults/>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: ApiResults is a component, you are just calling and treating it as a function `ApiResults()`, you need to render. Also it has no `data` in scope, you need to pass it as component's props. I highly suggest to go over the React docs and tutorials before.

Answer (score 2):

In order for your component to re-render when a variable changes that variables need to be a state.
You can use useState hook to create a state and every time you change that with the setter your component should rer-ender and show its real-time content